# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in spark-submit

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, jar

I've built the project from https://github.com/tribbloid/spookystuff/tree/branch-0.4 here using

> MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m" mvn package -DskipTests=true

from here https://gist.github.com/titipata/13fad88df5525d607f24

Then I'm using a fat-jar created in `core/target/x-jar-with-dependencies.jar` in my own separate project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.tribbloid.spookystuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>spookystuff-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <version>0.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/x-jar-with-dependencies.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

And I'm also creating fat-jar of this project I'm using `spookystuff` in (`y-jar-with-dependencies.jar` lets say).

Now when running

> spark-submit --class org.webcrawler.core.Driver --master local[*] /path/to/my/y-jar-with-dependencies.jar

I get an error stating

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/tribbloids/spookystuff/actions/Action

Investigation:

> jar -tvf /path/to/my/x-jar-with-dependencies.jar | grep "com/tribbloids/spookystuff/actions/Action"

I get results but

> jar -tvf /path/to/my/y-jar-with-dependencies.jar | grep "com/tribbloids/spookystuff/actions/Action"

I get no classes found. Where am I wrong in all this?

Comment: your `-y-jar` doesn't have that class, how are you building the `y-jar` with dependencies.

Comment: I am using `maven-assembly-plugin` plugin to create the fat-jar.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/fahadsiddiqui/cbe4c85e75568961696604ccce211bb0#file-pom-xml have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got resolved my problem following https://eureka.ykyuen.info/2014/06/10/maven-include-system-scope-dependency-in-maven-assembly-plugin/ posted by [Ykyuen](https://eureka.ykyuen.info/author/ykyuen/).